# Does this error MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered show only in logs or a Yellow Page?

Tags: configuration, media-library

We are seeing this logs in our Sitecore application, we already saw some of the fixes and we are just wandering if this error makes the page in exception(yellow) page? or this has nothing to do in the page and it will loads fine and it will only log in the log file?